# Disable scrolling on specific area in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, gesturedetector, touchimageview

I have a ViewPager so inside this view pager I have different fragments so in first fragment I have a TouchImageView which contain 360 degree rotatable image. When I'm swiping left or right for the Touchimageview so back viewpager event also triggering means viewpager is scrolling so I want to disable viewpager touch event for this imageview area.

Eg: ViewPager -> Fragment -> TouchImageView

I have gone through several answers about disable to onInterceptTouchEvent() and onTouchEvent() based on need but its disabled complete view of the fragment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

ViewPager.java

```
public class MyCardViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean isScrollingEnabled = true;

public MyCardViewPager(@Nonnull Context context, @Nonnull AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyCardViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isScrollingEnabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    return false;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isScrollingEnabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return false;
}

public void enableScroll(boolean enable) {
    isScrollingEnabled = enable;
}
```

}

Fragment.java

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(@Nonnull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myCardViewPager = new MyCardViewPager(context);
    myCardViewPager.enableScroll(false);
    imageViewSwipeListener();
    }

    private void imageViewSwipeListener() {
        position = 18;
        objectList();
        imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight();
                position += 1;
                if (position == 36) {
                    position = 0;
                }
                imageview.setImageResource(objectList.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                super.onSwipeLeft();
                position -= 1;
                if (position == -1) {
                    position = 35;
                }
                imageview.setImageResource(objectList.get(position));
              }
        });
    }
```

OnSwipeTouchListener class

```
open class OnSwipeTouchListener(ctx: Context) : View.OnTouchListener {

private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector

companion object {

    private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
    private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100
}

init {
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(ctx, GestureListener())
}

override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}

private inner class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {


    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        var result = false
        try {
            val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
            val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight()
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft()
                    }
                    result = true
                }
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom()
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop()
                }
                result = true
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
        return result
    }
}

open fun onSwipeRight() {}

open fun onSwipeLeft() {}

open fun onSwipeTop() {}

open fun onSwipeBottom() {}
```

}

Comment: show what you have tried so far, mentioned methods are good clues, but may be improperly implemented. it would be easier to catch a bug in existing code rather that writing whole feature from scratch

Comment: sure @snachmsm I'll add my code

Answer (score 0):

```
swipeTouch = new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {...};
imageview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        swipeTouch.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        imageview.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

first line in this method is just passing every `MotionEvent motionEvent` to same `View`, which is default behavior without setting custom touch listener. BUT `onTouchEvent` method [returns boolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) indicating that this `View` consumed passed event. if default `onTouchEvent` returns `false` then same event is passed to `view`s parent, if it also wont consume it then, again, is passed up in hierarchy until some of parenting `View`s (`ViewGroup`s) will `return true` confirming it can handle this event.

your `imageview` is probably some custom/lib class, which occasionally (always?) `return false` allowing to dispatch touch events up in hierarchy to `ViewPager`, which can handle this touch and `return true`. thats why in above snippet `onTouch` method is returning `true` always when touch occurs on `imageview` - this touch is still passed to this `View`, but even if it isn't handled `return true` prevents dispatching same event up to parents

Comment: I have customized OnSwipeTouchListener class which is added to the imageview

Comment: how can I do it in my OnSwipeTouchListener class ?

Comment: you can have only one touch listener, but still you may have one listener grouping and calling some other. I've edited my answer, check out

Comment: tried the same way now my imageview touchevent is gone ....touchevent only working for view pager

Comment: maybe your custom `OnSwipeTouchListener` swallows `MotionEvent` and you should call `imageview.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)` at first? now i'm not shure what behavior you want to achieve, don't have more ideas... maybe post `imageview` class code + try to use your current code (as in question), but `return true` in `onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent)`, still calling `gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` before

Comment: As clearly metioned in my question I want to disable view pager events for its child view(imageview) only for specific area. I have tried your suggestion so now unable to do touch event for child view ie imageview